# Sort select list by count and value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html list

```
<select>
  <option value="w" count="1">w (1)</option>
  <option value="a" count="1">a (1)</option>
  <option value="d" count="5">d (5)</option>
  <option value="r" count="0">r (0)</option>
  <option value="q" count="0">q (0)</option>
  <option value="s" count="0">s (0)</option>
  <option value="b" count="5">b (5)</option>
</select>
```

I want the list to be order by `count` first, then by `value`.

Output:

```
<select>  
  <option value="b" count="5">b (5)</option>
  <option value="d" count="5">d (5)</option>
  <option value="a" count="1">a (1)</option>
  <option value="w" count="1">w (1)</option>
  <option value="q" count="0">q (0)</option>
  <option value="r" count="0">r (0)</option>
  <option value="s" count="0">s (0)</option>
</select>
```

I know how to sort by `count` OR by `value` but I don't find an easy way to combine them.

Sort by count:

```
select.sort(function (a, b) {
    var c1 = parseInt($(a).attr('count'), 10);
    var c2 = parseInt($(b).attr('count'), 10);
    return c1 < c2 ? 1 : c1 > c2 ? -1 : 0;
});
```

and by value

```
select.sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text());
});
```

I am thinking about building an object:

```
var map = {
    5: ['d', 'b'],
    1: ['a', 'w'],
    0: ['r', 'q', 's']
};
```

Then sort each keys:

```
function keys(map) {
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in map) {
        if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)) map[key].sort();
    }
    return keys;
}

keys(map);
map;
```

And finally reconstruct the `select` list.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select.sort(function (a, b) {
    var c1 = parseInt($(a).attr('count'), 10);
    var c2 = parseInt($(b).attr('count'), 10);

    if(c1 === c2){ // If the counts are equal, return the comparison for value.
        return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text());
    }
    // Otherwise, compare the counts.
    // (With numbers, you can just substract `b` from `a` in sort functions.)
    return c1 - c2;
});
```

With the comments removed, that's just 6 lines of code.

There's no need to wrap the second `return` in a `else`, because the sort function won't ever evaluate an `else`, if `c1 === c2`, since the `if` contains a `return` statement.

Now, the `sort` function expects `X<0, X=0 or X>0` to be returned (Where `X` is the output), depending on if `a` is less than, equal to, or greater than `b`. If you subtract `b` from `a`, you get the values you need.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just combine both functions into one like this:

```
select.sort(function (a, b) {
    var c1 = parseInt($(a).attr('count'), 10);
    var c2 = parseInt($(b).attr('count'), 10);

    if ( c1 == c2 ) {
      return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text());
    } else {
      return c1 < c2 ? 1 : -1;
    }
});
```